# Is it possible to align a paragraph vertically and horizontally in python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I know you can align a paragraph horizontally with `WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH`, I just wanted to know if it is possible to do something like in Word: "Layout > Align > Align Middle" to vertically center text on a document in python-docx.

Comment: I don't see any `Align` option on my version of Word. Are you maybe talking about a TextBox rather than actual document body content?

Comment: @scanny Are you using Word 2016? There should be an "Arrange" section.

Comment: No, sorry, I guess I can't help you. It does seem a bit odd though. Text in a document is flowed, meaning its vertical location is determined by its position in the document body. Aligning to the document would imply a free-floating item like a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently exists no way to do this in the library. HOWEVER, I found out that by aligning text in an existing document, then opening it with python-docx, you can simply edit the text and it will retain its formatting.

[image]

```
from docx import document

document = Document('template.docx')
# This just grabs the first paragraph, code assumes you've already applied formatting.
document.paragraphs[0].text = "Example Text"
document.save('output.docx')
```